# how is the journey of packet in kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, packet

I wanted to know what exactly does happen to a packet by the time it goes to a linux kernel, until it comes out of kernel and goes as application layer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about kernel working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice paper [PATH OF A PACKET IN THE LINUX
KERNEL STACK](http://hsnlab.tmit.bme.hu/twiki/pub/Targyak/Mar11Cikkek/Network_stack.pdf)(pdf), with examples and links to the kernel source code.

Comment: Thanks! By the way the paper you have sent me, is the only paper that I had before! 
Do you know anything else?

Comment: There is some old, but still useful article http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5617